# Leaflet Clustering with multiple layers (use MarkerCluster.LayerSupport?)

Tags: leaflet, markerclusterer

Alright, so I've tried and failed a number of times and dug through SE hoping to figure out my problems.

I've been basing a lot of my work off this SE post: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35788139/how-to-apply-leaflet-marker-cluster-using-layers/35788393#35788393).

I have been unable to make this work, mainly because of two errors, but the first one being an obvious hurdle to overcome first: [image]

Error 1:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Error 2:

> Uncaught TypeError: L.markerClusterGroup.layerSupport is not a function

So, I would like clustering to work with any layer that is turned on via the L.control.layers() function.

Here is my page, as it sits now: [TN Alcohol Map](http://millionsmaps.netne.net/brew/index.html)

And the code, sans headers/misc:

```js
// initialize the map
var map = L.map('map').setView([36.17, -86.78], 7);

// load a tile layer/base map
L.tileLayer('http://stamen-tiles-{s}.a.ssl.fastly.net/terrain/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
{
  attribution: 'Map tiles by <a href="http://stamen.com">Stamen Design</a>, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0">CC BY 3.0</a> &mdash; Map data &copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
  maxZoom: 18,
  minZoom: 7
}).addTo(map);

//attributes for basemap credit (lower right hand corner annotation)
var streetsAttr = 'Map tiles by <a href="http://stamen.com">Stamen Design</a>, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0">CC BY 3.0</a> &mdash; Map data &copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>';
var aerialAttr = 'Tiles &copy; Esri &mdash; Source: Esri, i-cubed, USDA, USGS, AEX, GeoEye, Getmapping, Aerogrid, IGN, IGP, UPR-EGP, and the GIS User Community';
var artsyfartsyAttr = 'Map tiles by <a href="http://stamen.com">Stamen Design</a>, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0">CC BY 3.0</a> &mdash; Map data &copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>';

//crete variables for the base map layer switcher
var streets = L.tileLayer('http://stamen-tiles-{s}.a.ssl.fastly.net/terrain/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {id: 'MapID', attribution: streetsAttr}),
    aerial   = L.tileLayer('http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}', {id: 'MapID', attribution: aerialAttr}),
    artsyfartsy = L.tileLayer('http://stamen-tiles-{s}.a.ssl.fastly.net/toner/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {id: 'MapID', attribution: artsyfartsyAttr});

//create baseMaps variable to store basemap layer switcher
var baseMaps = {
    "Streets": streets,
    "Aerial": aerial,
    "ArtsyFartsy": artsyfartsy
};

// BEER icon & load beer geojson
var beerIcon = L.icon({
  iconUrl: 'glass.png',
  iconSize: [24, 48]
});

var beerMarker = L.geoJson(false, {
  pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
    var marker = L.marker(latlng, {
      icon: beerIcon
    });
    //popup shows NAME, ADDRESS, URL and opens the URL in a new window/tab
    marker.bindPopup("<strong>" + feature.properties.NAME + "</strong><br/>" + feature.properties.STREETNUM + " " + feature.properties.STREET + ", " + feature.properties.CITY + "<br/>" + "<a target = _blank href=" +
      feature.properties.URL + ">" + feature.properties.URLDISPLAY + "</a>");
    return marker;
  }
}).addTo(map);

$.getJSON("breweries.geojson", function(data) {
  beerMarker.addData(data);
});

// WINE icon & load wine geojson
var wineIcon = L.icon({
  iconUrl: 'wine.png',
  iconSize: [48, 48]
});

var wineMarker = L.geoJson(false, {
  pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
    var marker = L.marker(latlng, {
      icon: wineIcon
    });
    //popup shows NAME, ADDRESS, URL and opens the URL in a new window/tab
    marker.bindPopup("<strong>" + feature.properties.NAME + "</strong><br/>" + feature.properties.STREETNUM + " " + feature.properties.STREET + ", " + feature.properties.CITY + "<br/>" + "<a target = _blank href=" +
      feature.properties.URL + ">" + feature.properties.URLDISPLAY + "</a>");
    return marker;
  }
}).addTo(map);

$.getJSON("wine.geojson", function(data) {
  wineMarker.addData(data);
});

//Define overlay maps (non-base layer maps)
var overlayMaps = {
    "Breweries": beerMarker,
    "Wineries": wineMarker
}; 

//Creates a Marker Cluster Group
var mcg = L.markerClusterGroup.layerSupport().addTo(map);

//Checking in the 'sub groups'
mcg.checkIn([
    beerMarker,
    wineMarker
]);

//baseMaps layer switcher
L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps).addTo(map);
```

Comment: The `leaflet.markercluster.layersupport-src` file that you are including as a script is actually an HTML document of the github page for the plugin you want. Use the actual js file, and I suspect that things will work much better for you.

Comment: Wow, do I feel dumb. Thank you Nathan.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As said by nathansnider in the question comment, the content of your `leaflet.markercluster.layersupport-src` file is not the JavaScript code of the markerCluster.LayerSupport plugin, but the GitHub HTML page that displays the code of that file, i.e. surrounded by plenty HTML code.

You should simply replace the content of your file by the content of the raw file here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ghybs/Leaflet.MarkerCluster.LayerSupport/master/leaflet.markercluster.layersupport-src.js

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/Jd8skZ1U0bWxgl2orJV6?p=preview

---

**Side note:**

If you just need the Layers Control to work with Leaflet.markercluster, there is another plugin that does just that and which is much simpler: [Leaflet.FeatureGroup.SubGroup](https://github.com/ghybs/Leaflet.FeatureGroup.SubGroup) (230 lines of code v.s. 600 lines for [Leaflet.MarkerCluster.LayerSupport](https://github.com/ghybs/Leaflet.MarkerCluster.LayerSupport) as of today).

In your case you would use it this way:

```js
// Create a normal Marker Cluster Group.
var mcg = L.markerClusterGroup().addTo(map);

// Create SubGroups.
var beerMarkerSub = L.featureGroup.subGroup(mcg).addTo(map);
var wineMarkerSub = L.featureGroup.subGroup(mcg).addTo(map);

// For Layers Control.
var overlayMaps = {
    "Breweries": beerMarkerSub,
    "Wineries": wineMarkerSub
};

// That is it! No need to check-in.
```

Code specific for your application, since you load GeoJSON data by AJAX:

```js
var beerMarker = L.geoJson(null, beerOptions); // DO NOT add to map.
var wineMarker = L.geoJson(null, wineOptions); // Same story.

$.getJSON("breweries.geojson", function(data) {
  beerMarker.addData(data); // GeoJSON conversion.
  // Then transfer all features into the corresponding sub-group.
  beerMarker.eachLayer(function (layer) {
    layer.addTo(beerMarkerSub);
  });
});

$.getJSON("wine.geojson", function(data) {
  wineMarker.addData(data); // GeoJSON conversion.
  // Then transfer all features into the corresponding sub-group.
  wineMarker.eachLayer(function (layer) {
    layer.addTo(wineMarkerSub);
  });
});
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/x8vTLjE53TPiLd52BQ1d?p=preview

> Disclosure: I am the author of these plugins.

Comment: Thank you kindly. I feel embarrassed I loaded in the whole HTML and not just the JS. I switched to the Leaflet.FeatureGroup.SubGroup instead and it works like a charm! Many, many thanks for your help and for your work on these plugins. They work well and are visually quite appealing.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer. It worked for me really well. Great plugin!