# Using several Marker Cluster Groups displays overlapping Clusters

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I am using several `L.markerClusterGroup({})`'s so that I can switch them in a Layers Control.

But the Clusters hide behind each other.

I would like to be able to get the total number of both Clusters.

What am I missing?

[image: overlapping Clusters]

Comment: Do you mean you have several `L.markerClusterGroup`'s?

Comment: @ghybs yes I do

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The issue is that *each* [Leaflet Marker Cluster Group](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster) (i.e. `L.markerClusterGroup`) will perform its own clustering and render Clusters irrespective of what other Cluster Groups may display. Therefore if you have some individual Markers (or any point Features) that are in different Cluster Groups but close to each other, these Groups will display Clusters also close to each other, which may end up overlapping, especially at low zoom level, exactly like in your screenshot.

If you want your Markers to cluster *all together* (mixing "oranges with apples"), you should use a *single* Marker Cluster Group.

Now if I understand correctly, your "difficulty" is that you would like to be able to add and remove the Markers dynamically, i.e. in your case the user can use a [Layers Control](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.2.html#control-layers) to switch on/off some Features on map.

In that case, you would probably be interested in [Leaflet.FeatureGroup.SubGroup](https://github.com/ghybs/Leaflet.FeatureGroup.SubGroup) plugin (see [demo](http://ghybs.github.io/Leaflet.FeatureGroup.SubGroup/examples/subGroup-markercluster-controlLayers-realworld.388.html)). Simply create 1 subgroup per "switchable" Features Group and set their parent as your *single* Marker Cluster Group:

```js
var map = L.map('map', {
  maxZoom: 18,
}).setView([48.86, 2.35], 11);

var parentGroup = L.markerClusterGroup().addTo(map);

var overlays = {};

for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i += 1) {
  overlays['Group ' + i] = L.featureGroup.subGroup(
    parentGroup,
    getArrayOfMarkers()
  ).addTo(map);
}

L.control.layers(null, overlays, {
  collapsed: false,
}).addTo(map);

function getArrayOfMarkers() {
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i += 1) {
    result.push(L.marker(getRandomLatLng()));
  }
  return result;
}

function getRandomLatLng() {
  return [
    48.8 + 0.1 * Math.random(),
    2.25 + 0.2 * Math.random()
  ];
}

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!-- Leaflet assets -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.3/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-Rksm5RenBEKSKFjgI3a41vrjkw4EVPlJ3+OiI65vTjIdo9brlAacEuKOiQ5OFh7cOI1bkDwLqdLw3Zg0cRJAAQ==" crossorigin="" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.3/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-tAGcCfR4Sc5ZP5ZoVz0quoZDYX5aCtEm/eu1KhSLj2c9eFrylXZknQYmxUssFaVJKvvc0dJQixhGjG2yXWiV9Q==" crossorigin=""></script>

<!-- Leaflet.markercluster assets -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.3.0/dist/MarkerCluster.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.3.0/dist/MarkerCluster.Default.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.3.0/dist/leaflet.markercluster-src.js"></script>

<!-- Leaflet.FeatureGroup.SubGroup assets -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.featuregroup.subgroup@1.0.2/dist/leaflet.featuregroup.subgroup.js"></script>

<div id="map"></div>
```

See also [Cluster multiple Layers with markercluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33143237/cluster-multiple-layers-with-markercluster)

Note: for more complex use cases, there is also another plugin [Leaflet.MarkerCluster.LayerSupport](https://github.com/ghybs/Leaflet.MarkerCluster.LayerSupport).

See also [How to apply leaflet marker cluster using layers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35788139/how-to-apply-leaflet-marker-cluster-using-layers)

> Disclosure: I am the author of these plugins.

Comment: thank you so very much for the succinct information, got it to work

Comment: @ghybs this is great. Thanks for pointing me here. But I am not skilled enough to incorporate this into what I have done with my code here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56841425/jquery-leaflet-marker-layer-control-for-dynamic-custom-icons-with-clustering-plu