# Leaflet cluster and filter

Tags: dictionary, filter, leaflet

I own a website, it was made with Google Maps API. Due the increase of costs, I had to remake all the site with Leaflet. I am not developer, just designer with some knowledge, so my code is not pretty good.

I have been looking for a a way to add filtering to my code. In my DDBB there some tags, places are High, Medium and Low. is there any way to implement a filtering system in this code?

Here it is:

```
var mapa   = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png');

var satelite  = L.tileLayer('https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}');

var layerLabels;

var map = L.map('map', {
  center: [42.041, -5.098],
  zoom: 4,
  layers: [mapa],
  zoomControl: false
});
var geocoder = L.esri.Geocoding.geocodeService();                               
geocoder.geocode().text('<?php echo $address ?>').run(function (error, response) {
  map.fitBounds(response.results[0].bounds);                                            
});



//add zoom control with your options
L.control.zoom({position:'bottomright'}).addTo(map);

var baseLayers = {
  "Mapa": mapa,
  "Satelite": satelite
};
L.control.layers(baseLayers).addTo(map);                                    



/* preload */
var progress = document.getElementById('progress');
var progressBar = document.getElementById('progress-bar');
function updateProgressBar(processed, total, elapsed, layersArray) {
  if (elapsed > 1000) {
    // if it takes more than a second to load, display the progress bar:
    progress.style.display = 'block';
    progressBar.style.width = Math.round(processed/total*100) + '%';
  }

  if (processed === total) {
    progress.style.display = 'none';
    //console.log("acabamos de cargar");                                                
  }
}

var markers = L.markerClusterGroup({ 
  chunkedLoading: true, 
  chunkProgress: updateProgressBar,
  showCoverageOnHover: false,
  disableClusteringAtZoom: 12
});

var markerList = [];



//console.log('start creating markers: ' + window.performance.now());

var myIcon = L.icon({
  iconUrl: '/img/marker_mispicaderos.png',
  iconSize: [60, 60],
  iconAnchor: [22, 94],
  popupAnchor: [-3, -76]
});


for (var i = 0; i < addressPoints.length; i++) {
  var a = addressPoints[i];
  var title = '<div><h4>'+a[2]+'</h4><p style="text-align:justify;">'+a[5]+'</p><a href="/'+a[3]+'-'+a[4]+'" class="btn btn-blanco btn-block">Ver detalles</a></div>';
  var marker = L.marker(L.latLng(a[0], a[1]), { title: title, icon: myIcon});
  marker.bindPopup(title);
  markerList.push(marker);
  //console.log('marker '+title+'-lat '+a[0]+'-lng '+a[1]);
}


//console.log('start clustering: ' + window.performance.now());

markers.addLayers(markerList);
map.addLayer(markers);

//console.log('end clustering: ' + window.performance.now());



// AÑADE CONTROL PARA GEOLOCATE https://github.com/domoritz/leaflet-locatecontrol 
L.control.locate({
  strings: {
    title: "Averiguar mi posicion"
  }
}).addTo(map);




/* esri leaflet search plugin https://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/api-reference/controls/geosearch.html */
var searchControl = L.esri.Geocoding.geosearch({
  position: 'topleft',
  useMapBounds: false,
  placeholder: "Ej.: Barcelona ",
  title: "Buscador por dirección",
  zoomToResult: true,
  expanded: true,
  collapseAfterResult: false
}).addTo(map);                                      

var results = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);

searchControl.on('results', function(data){
  results.clearLayers();
  for (var i = data.results.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    results.addLayer(L.marker(data.results[i].latlng));
  }
});
```

Comment: Make three different MarkerClusterGroups, and add them to a L.Control.Layers. Alternatively create three L.LayerGroups, add them to both a L.Control.Layers and the MarkerClusterGroups, depending on how do you want to handle the clustering.

Comment: You would probably be interested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51544086/using-several-marker-cluster-groups-displays-overlapping-clusters/51549989#51549989

Comment: Yes it is IvanSanchez.
And as you see, I´m completely lost!! 
I had to do all this code without knowledge and I´m trying to implemente filters, but it´s imposible for a designer...